# Uploaded folder of images to Pinata (IPFS) but the URL structure is coming back strange

Tags: ipfs, nft, pinata

Im trying to create some NFTs. I've done this before and im familiar with the process but never encountered this issue before. I uploaded a folder of images, so I can include the CID in my metadata (.JSON files). For some reason when I click on files in the folder I uploaded on Pinata its adding characters to the URL that should not be there

Expected Result: `https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/[CID]/1.png`

What im getting: `https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/[CID]/%201.png`

Pinata/IPFS keeps appending "%20" to the beginning of my file names in the folder rather than just leaving it as "1.png"

Does anyone know what might be going on? I've tried deleting and re-uploading my files several times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means your files have a leading space. This can happen if you programmatically created it (easy to accidentally add a space in your file name).

%20 is the url encoding for a space: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Comment: Oh wow, thanks so much for this response. Sorry for the delayed response back, your help is greatly appreciated!